# How to avoid creating object inside object and push the elements directly into an array in express using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

`filesArray` is the array of objects means contain all files upload datas like path, filename etc. So I am just fetching the path and filename and pushing it into another array called `Bigpaths2`. So while I am pushing `Bigpaths2` into the `Addtasks` array's array `Bigpaths4clients` it get pushed successfully but by creating another array inside `Bigpaths4clients` and then get pushed in form of objects.

But I don't want that. I want to prevent that array creation. I just want all the paths object inside `Bigpaths2` should directly be pushed inside `Bigpaths4clients` array creating single objects. I have attached an image as well in last to conclude which i dont want. Check json format as well thanks!

```
var Bigpaths2 = [], paths;
    
filesArray.forEach(element => {
    paths = {
          "path": element.path,
          "name": element.filename
    };
    
    Bigpaths2.push(paths);
})

User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'Addtasks.commonID':cid }, 
    { $push: { 'Addtasks.$.Bigpaths4Clients': Bigpaths2 } },
    function (error, WriterData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } 
        else
        {
            console.log("success");
        }
    }
)
```

User schema:

```
[
    {
        "assignee" : "Charlotte Miles",
        "displayLock" : "none",
        "displayDelete" : "inline",
        "commonID" : "x0yosfn1uz",
        "status" : "Approved by Admin",
        "Date" : "Fri Sep 04 2020 15:36:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
        "exampleRadios" : "option1",
        "otherdetails" : "haha great!",
        "website" : "asad.com",
        "keywords" : "article importance, article generation, article quality",
        "words" : 12345,
        "topic" : "How article is generated?",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5211b29dc68d04244a6774"),
        "Bigpaths4Clients" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "name" : "api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll",
                    "path" : "public\\files\\api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "Bigpaths" : [ 
            {
                "path" : "public\\files\\api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll",
                "name" : "api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'Addtasks.commonID':cid }, 
    { $push: { 'Addtasks.$.Bigpaths4Clients': { $each: Bigpaths2 } } },
    function (error, WriterData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } 
        else
        {
            console.log("success");
        }
    }
)
```

`$each operator is used to append multiple values to the array field`.
In your case, MongoDB considering the whole `Bigpaths2 array as a single element to append to Bigpaths4Clients array`

here's the official dock link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array